# Supply an environment variable to a bash command that only accepts files

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to script the use of `ansible-vault` to encrypt file on a Linux based system. In this scenario I have an `ansible-vault` password to be used for encryption stored as an environment variable and I need to use this to encrypt the file.

The `ansible-vault` command can accept passwords in two ways. One requires manual entry of the password (see: `--ask-vault-pass`) and the other allows you to save the password in a file and use that (see: `--vault-password-file`). The `--ask-vault-pass` command will not work for this case as I want to avoid having to ask for user input.

I am hoping to use `--vault-password-file` to achieve this. For now my code is:

```
echo ${ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD} > .ansible_vault_temp
ansible-vault encrypt --vault-password-file=.ansible_vault_temp --output=encrypted_file.yml decrypted_file.yml
rm .ansible_vault_temp
```

However, I do not like creating a file and removing it on two different lines. Is there a possibility to pass `${ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD}` to the `ansible-vault` command in such a way that the command will see it as a file but no file will be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a process substitution:

```
ansible-vault encrypt --vault-password-file=<(echo "${ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD}") --output=encrypted_file.yml decrypted_file.yml
```

Comment: I can't remember if the process substitution exposes the password in some command line or not; it might be a risk.

Comment: (Said risk is why commands don't take passwords as command line arguments, but only from files or directly via the terminal.)

Comment: @chepner Do you know if that does happen? Surely that would make piping in Linux insecure as well? Isn't process substitution similar to piping?

Comment: It's not the pipe that is the problem, it's the password hard-coded in the command line.